# How do I uninstall xscreensaver from OSX?

Tags: macos, xscreensaver

I'm using OSX Yosemite. I installed xscreensaver from the DMG as described here: https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/download.html

Now I want to uninstall it (it's killed my desktop background).

There's nothing in the Applications folder, or in the [FAQ](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html).

How should I get rid of it?

Comment: how did you install it ?
usually you open the .dmg file and copy the "app" to applications. what did you do exactly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is given in **ReadMe** file included along with the installer

**To Uninstall**

Open the "`/Library/Screen Savers/`" folder and drag any unwanted savers to Trash.

[image]

I also expanded **Install Everything** package and found there is a preinstall script that mentions, install Screensaver and updater in `/System/Library/Screen Savers/`

So remove any unwanted screensavers from `/System/Library/Screen Savers/`